# Dataloader insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

Tags: data-loader, error

I've been stuck on this for hours, I've researched for hours, nothing relevant has surfaced.

So here goes:

Dataloader > Insert > Accounts From Production to Sandbox.

-I changed the OwnerID to my ID

-I'm an Admin so it shouldn't be permission related.

I'm getting this Error:

"insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: "000000000YYYXXX"

That ID leads to an Account In Production.

Comment: did you check the access the Account record?

Comment: What? I have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is thrown when you try to insert/update something that logically cannot be inserted/updated.

**Some examples:**

- You try to update a record that does not exist. Maybe the record was never there or it was deleted.
- You try to update an object field that cannot be set explicitly. These fields can only be updated by the implicitly. eg: object owner,
  CreatedById, CreatedDate, LastActivityDate, LastModifiedById,
  LastModifiedDate. You cannot explicitly update these fields.
- You are trying to give permission to someone but you yourself do not have permission for this.
- If you are trying to share "Record X" with "User Y" and you yourself do not have access to "Record x", this error happens Or if
  the "User Y" already has access to it.

if you have a way to bypass execution of triggers, flows and processes then would recommend to bypass them and perform the data load operation

Comment: Yes you're correct.

Comment: did you manage to figure out which category the issue was with you?

Comment: Ok I found the answer. There are many different scenarios that can cause this error.

My scenario was this (shamefully):

The account I was trying to push was a Child Account. The parent account had not been pushed yet.

In excel, I cleared the data under "PARENTID" and it pushed.

Comment: awesome.......

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the answer. There are many different scenarios that can cause this error.

My scenario was this (shamefully):

The account I was trying to push was a Child Account. The parent account had not been pushed yet.

In excel, I cleared the data under "PARENTID" and it pushed.